# Symfony post request body parameters?

Tags: rest, symfony, postman

I'm sending POST request by postman with header `application/json`
and the body:

```
{
    "name": "user"
}
```

And when I try to get this parameter from the request object
`$request->request->get('name')` I got null.
But when I use `$request->getContent()` I receive raw string.

Looks like my request is not parsed correctly. What is wrong with the request?

Update:

Turned out that docs not clear about that and I need to manually convert body to json. Don't really understand why not to do it in framework by default.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

That is the expected behavior. You are sendind a JSON string inside the body of the request.

In this case, you need [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to convert the JSON string into an array or object, in order to access the data.

```
$parameters = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
echo $parameters['name']; // will print 'user'
```

Comment: Hello @caconde !
Thanks for your answer. I don't know why this is an expected behavior. I'm sending a POST request the same way and the Request is normally fuelled. In PUT, not. I am confused. Can you you explain or give me a link ? TY

Answer (score 9):

Although the accepted answer is correct, I would like to add here that there are 2 ways of doing so.

```
$payload = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
echo $payload['name']; // will print 'user'
```

or

```
$payload = json_decode($request->getContent(), false);
echo $payload->name; // will print 'user'
```

By default, the json_decode returns an object unless otherwise specified by the second parameter.

- true: array
- false: object (default)

Answer (score 6):

If you want to decode the request body to an array, there is a convenient helper method called `toArray`. You can read more about accessing request data in the [Symfony docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html#accessing-request-data)

```php
$request->toArray();
```

Comment: To clarify, it also converts an array from the body if it is a JSON. So this `$data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);` is the same as `$data = $request->toArray();` in the case of a JSON.

Answer (score 2):

Answer from Cacanode is correct - you can decode json from the $request->getContent()

However, if you want to make your life easier you can consider using FOSRestBundle. Specifically the "body_listener" funcationality: https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSRestBundle/body_listener.html

This bundle has both JSON and XML decoders already installed - and you can add some new custom decoder if you want.

Answer (score -1):

Using Symfony 4.3 you could use the component:

```
...
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

...

public function doSomething(Request $request){
        $a = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);

        return $this->json($a);
}
```

This will return the same json object you sent.

Comment: Thanks for the replay, could you be more specific? I think it is a simple example of receiving a json body and returning the same object as json, using Symfony Request.