# get data from postman request with data in body

Tags: php, symfony, postman

I have a postman request with some data in the body like that :

```
{
    "informations" : {
        "contact" :[
        {
    "email" : 'email@email.fr',
    "phone" : 0111111111,
        }
    ]
    }
}
```

I symfony side, I can get theses data with :

```
$data = $request->getContent();
dd($data);
```

But I can't access to the "contact" array, I tried this :

```
dd($data['informations']['contact']);
```

And I get this error : Warning: Illegal string offset 'informations'

What is my mistake ? thanks

EDIT :
I also tried to use decode_json :

```
        $data = json_decode($data, true);
        dd($data);
```

And it return me NULL

I tried a json_last_error_message() and it return me a "Syntax error"

Comment: The error doesn't appear to relate to the code you've shown... "lead" is not mentioned anywhere here, except in the error message. Double-check which line number and file the error message is referring to.

Comment: I edited my post, its not lead, but information , wrong copy paste sorry

Comment: That is just a json string. You need to `json_decode($data)` first, then you should be able to access it as an array like that.

Comment: I already tried to use the json_decode, but it return me NULL, what can be the issue ?

Comment: Have you tried `json_decode($data, true)`? for associative array (think this is default anyways)? Update your question with you trying json_decode and how you're outputting this.

Comment: @Bossman it's not the default, no (which you can [easily check](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php))

Comment: @yonea if json_decode fails, you can try using [json_last_error_msg()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php) after the json_encode command to find if there was an error while it was trying to decode

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57281083/symfony-post-request-body-parameters btw

Comment: @ADyson I did it and I have a syntax error, but I don't see where can be my error in my code..

Comment: In a json viewer online, it gets parse errors. The json is not valid. Need to look into that first. Try it for [yourself here](https://jsonformatter.org/json-viewer)

Comment: That's true - did you try to validate the JSON at all? e.g. in something like https://jsonlint.com/ you can paste the JSON and see if there are any errors. For example, an obvious error is that in JSON, you must use double-quotes for string values. So `'email@email.fr'` must be changed to `"email@email.fr"`. Note that this is stricter than if you're writing object literals in JavaScript, even though the syntax appears to be similar (and indeed, JSON is derived from JavaScript Object Notation...hence the name).

Comment: Also, `"phone": 0111111111,` must be changed to `"phone": 111111111` or maybe `"phone": "0111111111"` (depending on your requirements) because a) a numeric value with a leading 0 isn't considered a valid number (you would never write a mathematical number like that - a phone number is actually more like a string which happens to consist entirely of digits), and b) you can't have a trailing comma without any more properties following it. I suggest consulting a JSON guide and/or the specification (available online) if you're unsure about the correct syntax and formatting.

Comment: thanks for the link, I will try to found my syntaxt error, I never use json, I will check a guide or doc for that, thanks :)

Comment: Heh, just for funsies, i just pasted your JSON into ChatGPT and asked it to make it valid, it did `{"informations":{"contact":[{"email":"email@email.fr","phone":111111111}]}}` and gave an explanation of all the errors..

Answer (score 0):

It is related with phone type. 'Numbers in JSON must be an integer or a floating point.' Integer(phone number) can not start with 0. You can convert to string or replace the zero.
You can try with

```
{
    "informations" : {
        "contact" :[
        {
    "email" : "email@email.fr",
    "phone" : "0111111111"
        }
    ]
    }
}
```

OR

```
{
    "informations" : {
        "contact" :[
        {
    "email" : "email@email.fr",
    "phone" : 111111111
        }
    ]
    }
}
```