# Retrieveing data from an ajax request in symfony

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, symfony

I  wrote an ajax request in javascript to retrive the state of a checkbox,  true or false. I want to retrive that data in a symfony controller. My ajax request seems to work but I keep getting null when I try to retrieve the state of the checkbox in the controller.

```
<label for="myCheckbox">My Checkbox</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheckbox" name="myCheckbox">

<script>

const checkboxAutoAll = document.querySelector("#myCheckbox");
const url = '/'

checkboxAutoAll.addEventListener("click", function () {
  const checkboxState = checkboxAutoAll.checked ? true : false;
  //console.log("Checkbox State:", checkboxState);

  const requete = new XMLHttpRequest();
  requete.open("POST", url, true);
  requete.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

  requete.onload = function () {
    if (requete.status >= 200 && requete.status < 300) {
      // Success!
      console.log("Request successful, response:", requete.responseText);
    } else {
      // We reached the server, but it returned an error
      console.error(
        "Server responded with an error:",
        requete.status,
        requete.statusText
      );
    }
  };

  requete.onerror = function () {
    console.error("Request failed due to a network error");
  };

  const data = JSON.stringify({ isHoraireAutoAll: checkboxState });
  requete.send(data);
  console.log("Sending AJAX request to:", url, "with data:", data); // Added this line for clarity
});
 
</script>
```

In my symfony controller I to retieve the data from the ajax request, but I do a dump of data, all I get is null.

```
#[Route('/', name: 'app_main', methods: ['GET', 'POST'])]
    public function index(Request $request): Response
    {   $data = $request->get('myCheckbox');
        dump($data);
}
```

I have tried to download this bundle to or this other similar question to no avail
[Symfony post request body parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57281083/symfony-post-request-body-parameters)
https://github.com/php-bundles/json-request-bundle

Comment: Try not sending it as JSON - it's only one value anyway. And also `isHoraireAutoAll` clearly doesn't match `myCheckbox`. You're asking the php to find a variable name which you didn't send

Comment: I've tried isHoraireAutoAll and it returned null also, I've change to myCheckbox to see if it would work.

Comment: What could I send the data as then? I'm new to writing ajax request.

Comment: Welcome to SO ! Have you looked into this [Documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html#accessing-request-data) ? Maybe this question have a correct answer to your issue, see: [SYmfony Post Request Body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57281083/symfony-post-request-body-parameters)

Comment: Just regular form-url-encoded data would be fine. But JSON can also be used if you adjust the php code as Shunka shows